# Cypress using typescript - Getting no spec files were found error

Tags: angular, typescript, automation, cypress

Getting the error "Can't run because no spec files were found. , even though .ts spec file is available in Cypress.

Run the following command in terminal:

```js
npx cypress run --spec="./cypress/integration/specs/Test1.spec.ts".
```

Tried to run in Cypress test runner using "npx cypress open", but the spec file is not displayed in runner

tsconfig.json file:

```
 {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2017",
    "lib": ["es2017", "dom"],
    "types": ["cypress", "node"],
    "baseUrl": "./"
  },
  "include": ["./**/*.ts"]
}
```

Test1.spec.ts file:

```
/// <reference types="Cypress" />

describe('Google Navigation', () => {
    it('Google Search',() => {
        cy.visit('https://www.google.com');

    });
});
```

Folder structure:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change the `=` into a space

```js
npx cypress run --spec "cypress/integration/specs/Test1.spec.ts"
```

[cypress run --spec](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/command-line#cypress-run-spec-lt-spec-gt)

Comment: Removed = and tried npx cypress run --spec "cypress/integration/specs/Test1.spec.ts". Same issue, getting error 'Can't run because no spec files were found.'

Comment: What specPattern did you specify in cypress.config.js?

Comment: Got it, Thanks. Had used specPattern: 'cypress/integration/specs/*.js'  changed to specPattern: 'cypress/integration/specs/*.ts'. Now its working